import stylesheet in another stylesheet
I have 2 CSS files that I need to be merged into 1 CSS file.
Normally this would work with @import.
Using an @import at the top of one of the files and done.
But I think this case is special. the first CSS part (the :root part) is dynamically generated with different colors each time. therefore I want both the css files being merged into 1 file before it is served to the html.
NOTE:
I cannot edit the html or any javascript. I can only manipulate the css-stylesheet.
QUESTION
Is it possible to let the first css part work in any shape or form where I don't stitch the 2 stylesheets together into 1 big css file? if possible I want to avoid this because of readability, upkeep and other things.
Dummy Data
dummy data will explain the problem. IRL file number 2 is over 5K lines of code. This will probably be split up in the future.
So in the first CSS (this is also the css I want to use) I have decleared the following:
:root {
--var1: #7B82CE;
--var2: #000000;
--var3: #FFFFFF;
}

@import url('https://link.com/css.css');

in the https://link.com/css.css this file looks like this.
body {
  background-color:(var(--var1));
}

text {
  background-color:(var(--var2));
}

button {
  background-color:(var(--var3));
}

EDIT:
Code below to solve this problem works, but i'm not looking for this.
I don't want the css code (5K lines) to be easily accessable by humans.
that is why I split this up.
a user can interact with the first small part of the css code (root-colors) and nothing else
@import url('https://link.com/variables.css');

body {
  background-color:(var(--var1));
}

text {
  background-color:(var(--var2));
}

button {
  background-color:(var(--var3));
}



learn some backend language/configuration. What you are describing is not the purpose of CSS/HTML, you need something else to manage/generate the files

your issue is due to the order between @import command and css rules.
@import should be placed at top of css document to avoid confusion
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_import_rule.php
to solve your issue do the opposite the other file at the beginning of the file with variable used
@import url('https://link.com/variables.css');

body {
  background-color:(var(--var1));
}

text {
  background-color:(var(--var2));
}

button {
  background-color:(var(--var3));
}



thank you for the response. unfortunately this is not an option, as I don't want to give away my css code.
made an edit to my question. sorry @jeremy-denis I forgot to add that part
